# Wix Help: Is there a way to add a left and right button to a repeater instead of having a scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, repeater, velo

Does anyone know a work around to get a left and right button to work on a repeater using the Wix Platform? Currently the repeater only lets you view other items within it using the scroll bar, but instead of scrolling through, I want it to where I can click the right button or left button to view the next/previous items.

Comment: Does https://support.wix.com/en/article/adding-and-setting-up-a-pagination-bar helps?

Comment: Can you add a link so we can see how your repeater looks with a scroll bar?

Comment: Would the following be what you are looking for? I've just coded it, it's fully custom. See: https://thefashionsocietyh.editorx.io/tfs-dev-x/page-3-test

Comment: @user1098973 Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Im thinking when I was coding it, I was making the whole repeater scroll and could not for the life of me figure out how to make each item in the repeater scroll instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned, I've implemented this, but I prefer you figure it out yourself. In essence you will need following logic for moving elements from right to left https://www.javatpoint.com/c-program-to-left-rotate-the-elements-of-an-array The inverse logic can be used to move elements from left to right.

Grab a piece of paper, build your logic and then map it to Velo code.

The following snippet will give you a head start:

```js
$w.onReady(function () {
    
    var obj_cp = {}
    obj_cp.Colors = ["rgb(122,160,187)","rgb(127,91,63)","rgb(93,50,32)","rgb(49,106,144)","rgb(74,135,152)","rgb(90,173,141)","rgb(127,108,75)","rgb(41,22,19)","rgb(81,74,45)","rgb(45,25,12)","rgb(111,109,72)","rgb(112,110,73)","rgb(61,49,35)","rgb(38,21,18)","rgb(207,209,174)","rgb(196,161,149)","rgb(227,228,230)","rgb(153,192,207)","rgb(94,130,152)","rgb(144,238,144)","rgb(165,168,172)","rgb(108,121,120)","rgb(88,64,60)","rgb(138,111,58)","rgb(116,77,28)","rgb(91,42,8)","rgb(73,42,28)","rgb(154,189,198)","rgb(153,157,89)","rgb(85,116,135)","rgb(133,128,98)","rgb(118,97,88)","rgb(69,71,70)"];

    initRepeater(obj_cp.Colors);
    
    $w("#button156").onClick( (event) => { //switch position of colors: from left to right

        var lastColor;
        var it;
        
        $w("#repeater1").forEachItem(($item, itemData, index_i) => {
            if(index_i === nbItems-1){
                //extract last color
                lastColor = $item("#box251").style.backgroundColor;
                
                $w("#repeater1").forEachItem(($item, itemData, index_j) => {
                    //get current item and store it in the next item 
                });
                
                //store last element in first pos
                item = $w("#repeater1").data[0]._id;
                $w("#repeater1").forItems( [item], ($item, itemData, index) => {
                    $item("#box251").style.backgroundColor = lastColor;
                });
            }
        });
        

    });

    $w("#button159").onClick( (event) => { //switch position of colors: from right to left

        var firstColor;
        
        $w("#repeater1").forEachItem(($item, itemData, index_i) => {
            if(index_i === 0){
                //extract first color
                firstColor = $item("#box251").style.backgroundColor;
                $w("#repeater1").forEachItem(($item, itemData, index_j) => {

                    //get next item and store it in the current item
                });
                //store first element in last position
                item = $w("#repeater1").data[nbItems-1]._id;
                $w("#repeater1").forItems( [item], ($item, itemData, index) => {
                    $item("#box251").style.backgroundColor = firstColor;
                });             
            }
        });
    });

    


});

function initRepeater(colors) { //pass colors
    
    $w("#repeater1").forEachItem(($item, itemData, index) => {
        $item("#box251").style.backgroundColor = colors[index]; 
    });

}
```